# Button Icon in datatable non visible in some orgs

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lightning-buttonicon

I have a lwc datatable with dynamic button-icon which depending on a field value changes icon.

```
this.columns = [...this.columns, { type: "button-icon", fixedWidth: 50, typeAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName : 'buttonIcon' }, alternativeText: this.labels.toggleButtonLabel, variant: "container", class : 'slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-large' } }];
```

Toggle logic:

```
changeButtonIcon() {
        this.servicesSelectedData.forEach(row => {
            if (row.BAT__Complimentary_c__c) {
                console.log("comp. on");
                row.buttonIcon = 'utility:toggle_on';
            } else {
                console.log("comp. off");
                row.buttonIcon = 'utility:toggle_off';
            }
        });
    }
```

We use namespace (BAT) and create a package version to install in various orgs. In some orgs the icons are visible whereas in some they are not, for example in QA the icons are not visible but they can be clicked and logic of the method in `onrowaction` of the datatable works fine.

Any suggestion as how to make the icons visible?